# Postgresql, comparing text as datetime

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with two columns of "text" type where in one is a date in format 10.03.2013. and in second is time in format 15:45:32. Since both are text I would like to know if is possible with PostgreSQL those strings compare with windows DateTime value.

I was try to get records with BETWEEN() but didn't get nothing.

```
"(mydate BETWEEN " & fromdate.Date.ToString & _
       " AND " & todate.Date.ToString & ") AND _
 (mytime BETWEEN " & fromdate.TimeOfDay.ToString & _
       " AND " & todate.TimeOfDay.ToString & ")"
```

mydate and mytime are columns while fromdate and to date are windows datetime types.

Any advice?

Comment: What language is this supposed to be? Why not first construct a timestamp type of value from the separate date+time fields?

Comment: This is visual basic where i make commands like strings. Second, because data already exists.

Comment: Or maybe I understand wrong? Can I construct timmestamp from showed data and mented datatype (text)? And how?

Comment: Do **not** store dates or timestamp as text (or varchar). That will give you a lot of trouble in the long run. Always use the proper datatype.

Comment: user: Read http://bobby-tables.com/ and search for `"SQL injection" "visual basic" OR VB`. Your SQL doesn't work because you're doing a *lexical* ordering comparison of text strings that happen to be dates and times. Use the database `timestamp` or `timestamptz` types. wildplasser: Be very, very glad you haven't had to deal with VB or VBA.

Comment: What is visual basic? A basic for visual people :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turn those columns into a timestamp type:

```
select ...
from ...
where
    to_timestamp(mydate || mytime, 'DD.MM.YYYYHH24:MI:SS') between
        '2012-01-20 10:23:12'
        and
        '2012-01-20 11:47:03'
```

Comment: Can't get that working. I wrongly represent date in question. Those date is in format 10.03.2013 without last point. May this be a problem?

Comment: @user973238 Yes that can be a problem. I edited the answer to accommodate the date format.

Comment: @user973238 I mean not the point absence but the `dd.mm.yyyy` format. I first guessed it was `mm.dd.yyyy` as in the USA. But after you comment I saw you are from Croatia so it probably is `dd.mm.yyyy` like here in Brazil.

Comment: Of course Colorado, thank you, I will fight forward to get results in this situation.

Comment: I finally GET IT :) PostgreSQL is amazing!